# How to set Azure AD user "Preferred language" property?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In the user properties tab, the Preferred language field appears in the Identity section. But when I want to edit the identity section, the Preferred language field does not appear. How do I update the Preferred language field?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, there are few user properties like *preferred language* where you cannot update them directly from Azure Portal. In such cases, make use of **Microsoft Graph** queries or **PowerShell** commands.

I have one Azure AD user named **`Sri`** where **preferred language** is not set like below:

[image]

To update the **preferred language** field of above user, I ran below MS Graph query in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) by granting required permissions like this:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sri@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/
{
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal by refreshing the page, **preferred language** field updated successfully like below:

[image]

Similarly, you can make use of below MS Graph PowerShell commands to set Azure AD user **"Preferred language"** property:

```
Connect-MgGraph
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users
$userId = "xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx"
$params = @{
    preferredLanguage = "en-US"
}
Update-MgUser -UserId $userId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Microsoft Graph Getting preferred language - Microsoft Q&A by **soumi-MSFT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/61943/microsoft-graph-getting-preferred-language)

Comment: thank you for answer. I am getting the following error while sending the request. "Method Not Allowed - 405 "

https://www.linkpicture.com/q/3_73.png
-----
https://www.linkpicture.com/q/4_201.png

Comment: I think you signed in with Microsoft account as it's showing Tenant as **Personal**. Make sure to sign in with Azure AD local account that ends with `.onmicrosoft.com` and run the query again.